# How to get the position of chart title in Excel by C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, office-automation

I have a chart worksheet in Excel file. Now, I want to know the chart title is above or center overlay. I found some code on the internet. But it's just help me to set up the location of the chart title.

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoChartElementType m=oWB.Charts[1].ChartElementType();
MessageBox.Show(m.gettype().ToString());
```

I want to get the result "msoElementChartTitleAboveChart" or "msoElementChartTitleCenteredOverlay".

Sorry if my English is not good.

I am looking to hearing from you.

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you don't know what property or method to use when dealing with the Excel object model you may try using the VBA macro recorder available in Excel, so you could do the required steps manually in Excel and then get the code generated for you.

Comment: I've tried macro.
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
End Sub